# KDE: Power management configuration module could not be loaded

Tags: kde, power-management, kde-neon

I use KDE 5.15.3 on the latest KDE Neon, and recall this problem happened with Linux Mint 19 + an older version of KDE (don't recall which) as well.

Intermittently, after booting I don't have the battery-widget in my task-bar (so I can't see how much battery is remaining). When this happens and I try to open the energy saving dialog, it tells me

```
Power management configuration module could not be loaded.  
The Power Management Service appears not to be running.  
This can be solved by starting or scheduling it inside "Startup and Shutdown"
```

Also, when this occurs, `Hibernate`/`Standby` option is missing from the shutdown menu.

Usually the problem clears when I reboot the system; sometimes log out and back in clears it. Either resolution is not permanent.

Note: When I go to `System settings > Startup and Shutdown` I don't have a tab called `Service manager` (as suggested in many threads I found on this topic). I only have `Background Services` and when choosing this one, there is no entry containing the word `Power` (Neither is it in any other tabs I see under `Startup and Shutdown`). And I don't have an option to add anything to the list.

Running `journalctl -r` contains the following, which seems kinda related to the problem:

```
Apr 01 12:35:20 workstation dbus-daemon[785]: [system] Reloaded configuration
Apr 01 12:35:20 workstation dbus-daemon[785]: Unknown group "power" in message bus configuration file
Apr 01 12:35:20 workstation dbus-daemon[785]: Unknown username "whoopsie" in message bus configuration file
```

Another solution suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/537353/kde-power-management-system-could-not-be-initialized#) is to re-install `upower`, but this didn't have any effect on the situation. Additionally `ps -e | grep upower` does find `5399 ? 00:00:00 upowerd` so I guess the problem is not, that `upower`isn't running.

EDIT:
Running `journalctl -b 0 | grep -i 'powerdevil'` as suggested in the comments, yields this output when the problem occurs:

```
Jun 30 09:38:35 workstation dbus-daemon[751]: [system] Activating service name='org.kde.powerdevil.discretegpuhelper' requested by ':1.37' (uid=1000 pid=1271 comm="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexec/org_kde_powerdev" label="unconfined") (using servicehelper)
Jun 30 09:38:35 workstation org.kde.powerdevil.discretegpuhelper[1347]: QDBusArgument: read from a write-only object
Jun 30 09:38:35 workstation org.kde.powerdevil.discretegpuhelper[1347]: QDBusArgument: read from a write-only object
Jun 30 09:38:35 workstation org.kde.powerdevil.discretegpuhelper[1347]: QDBusArgument: read from a write-only object
Jun 30 09:38:35 workstation dbus-daemon[751]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.kde.powerdevil.discretegpuhelper'
Jun 30 09:38:35 workstation dbus-daemon[751]: [system] Activating service name='org.kde.powerdevil.backlighthelper' requested by ':1.37' (uid=1000 pid=1271 comm="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexec/org_kde_powerdev" label="unconfined") (using servicehelper)
Jun 30 09:38:35 workstation org.kde.powerdevil.backlighthelper[1358]: QDBusArgument: read from a write-only object
Jun 30 09:38:35 workstation org.kde.powerdevil.backlighthelper[1358]: QDBusArgument: read from a write-only object
Jun 30 09:38:35 workstation org.kde.powerdevil.backlighthelper[1358]: QDBusArgument: read from a write-only object
Jun 30 09:38:35 workstation dbus-daemon[751]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.kde.powerdevil.backlighthelper'
```

EDIT2:
After doing some more research on this topic I stumbled upon these GitHub issues:
- https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/issues/47760
- https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/issues/24563
I did inspect my `~/.config/ksmserverrc` but I don't seem to have weird paths in there. Also I do start with an empty session anyways so this shouldn't be a problem anyways...

Comment: I have no experience with Neon, so I can't be sure, but I think you should search for issues with PowerDevil, KDE's power management tool. Have you tried something as `journalctl -b 0 | grep -i 'powerdevil'`? You may want to exclude messages with low priority with, e.g. `journalctl -p 0..7` and search messages about previous boots with e.g. `journalctl -b -1` (last boot; -2 is second to last, ...).

Answer (score 5):

```
Power management configuration module could not be loaded.  
The Power Management Service appears not to be running.  
This can be solved by starting or scheduling it inside "Startup and Shutdown"
```

Refers to `/etc/xdg/autostart`

In `powerdevil.desktop` you'll see:

```
Exec=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexec/org_kde_powerdevil"
```

Run that in a shell:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexec/org_kde_powerdevil
```

For me  power management configuration module runs then.